# On driving a car on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, curves, spheres, chaos-theory

Suppose I was driving a car on a solid sphere of radius $R$ at a constant speed. I constantly take a left turn always at the same angle. If the sphere was flat — flat Earth? :) — I would drive in circles of radius $T$.

1. How does my trajectory on the sphere look like?
2. When will my path be periodic?
3. If the path is not periodic, is it space-filling or will there be regions I will never get close to?
4. Will I visit certain places more often?
5. How many self-intersections will my trajectory make and where will they be?
6. Will my self-intersections be at all kinds of angles or a only at a few?
7. Is the trajectory chaotic when it is not periodic?
8. Is there a closed form?

Comment: I feel like this is too many questions for one post, but let's see what others gotta say about that.

Comment: Turning at the same angle with respect to what?

Comment: What does this mean "I constantly take a left turn always at the same angle".

Comment: Sounds like you're going to end up with small circles or loxodromes, depending on what you mean.

Comment: Loxodromes make more sense than circles however I think they only Take turn at specific Places , not continuously? I think it will be neither. Loxodromes end up in poles ( world analogue ) , so they converge to a point while this does not ?

Answer (score 5):

I take this image from my MO post,
[Curves of constant curvature on an ellipsoid](https://mathoverflow.net/q/102734/6094):

[image]

There I say,

> the curves of constant geodesic curvature on a geometric sphere are all circles: simple, closed curves that are geometric circles lying in a plane.

Comment: Just what I didn’t have the tools to describe. Thanks.

Comment: The questions asked in the link seem way more general and advanced. Indeed a nice picture but what is the simple proof ? Sorry if I missed it. Im not so good at geometry.

Comment: See question 7 at [this HW assignment](https://www.math.uci.edu/~ndonalds/math162b/hw5.pdf): "In this question we show that the only curves of constant geodesic curvature on the sphere are circles."

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to say that the path the car takes has the same curvature at every point, then of course the car travels in a (small) circle. I don’t see any other way of interpreting your word “always”.

Comment: Perhaps the margin of this page is not too narrow for a proof?

Comment: I really doubt that !! Especially When $T >> R $

Comment: Well @mick , I was thinking of a “curvature” to be defined in some *intrinsic* way. This is so far out of my area of competence that I may be blowing smoke, but I imagined that you’d need to do that using some fancy gadget like a connection on the $2$-sphere, that defined the curvature to be zero for a geodesic.